# Lebesgue integral $\geq1$ for $f_n \rightarrow 0$ uniformly in every compact set of $ \mathbb{R}$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, sequence-of-function

Is this true or false?

$\exists f_n:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+, n\in \mathbb{N}$ sequence of Lebesgue integrable functions  such that $f_n \rightarrow 0$ uniformly in every compact $K \subseteq \mathbb{R} $ but $\int_\mathbb{R} f_n dλ \geq1 $ for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: *Hint* you can find such as sequence in $C_c(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: What is this symbol for? I think I have learned it differently.. @user10354138

Comment: I think for $f_n(x)=\cases{n, &if $x \in [0,\frac{1}{n-1})$ \cr 0 & otherwise \cr} $ I have what I want.

Comment: Convergence of this sequence is not uniform on $[-1,1]$. Think about translations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think for $f_n(x)=\cases{1/n, &if $x \in [0,n]$ \cr 0 & otherwise \cr} $ I have what I want.